# Get-Adgroup only global

Tags: powershell, scripting

Hi there i need to locate only groups with a specific name which are global. I can't find any filter or Attribute which says a group is local or global. Can someone help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on type of group. It is called GroupScope. Test this for example

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"}
```

For a specific name

```
$GroupName = "My Group"
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq $GroupName -and GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"}
```